# ngrx4 multiple actions in effects -> forkJoin not working as expected

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to call multiple actions and wait for them to finish until I return the SYNC_SUCCESS action and dismiss the loading screen. But I can't get it to work.

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong here?

AppEffect:

```
@Effect()
syncMasterData$ = this.actions$
    .ofType<AppActions.SyncMasterdata>(AppActions.SYNC_MASTERDATA)
    .mergeMap(() => 
    {
        return Observable.forkJoin(
            Observable.of(new BarcodeConfigActions.Sync)
        ).map(() => new AppActions.SyncingSuccess);
    })
```

BarcodeConfigEffect

```
@Effect() sync$ = this.actions$
    .ofType<BarcodeConfigActions.Sync>(BarcodeConfigActions.SYNC)
    .mergeMap(() => this.apiProvider.getBarcodeConfig())
    .map((barcodeConfigs: BarcodeConfig[]) =>
    {
        let barcodeConfigState = <barcodeConfig.State>{};
        barcodeConfigState.tenant = "COOKIE";
        barcodeConfigState.barcodeConfig = barcodeConfigs;
        return new BarcodeConfigActions.SyncSuccess({ barcodeConfigs: barcodeConfigState });
    })
    .catch((error) =>
    {
        this._store.dispatch(new AppActions.UnexpectedError(error));
        return Observable.of(new BarcodeConfigActions.SyncFailed)
    })
```

AppAction:

```
export class SyncMasterdata implements Action
{
    readonly type = SYNC_MASTERDATA;
}
```

BarcodeConfigAction:

```
export class Sync implements Action
{
    readonly type = SYNC;
}
```

That way the barcodeconfigeffect -> sync won't be called. If I remove the forkjoin and just post the Observable.of(new BarcodeConfigActions.Sync) it works but I can't dispatch more actions.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, it seems like you want to ensure that a `BarcodeConfigActions.SyncSuccess` (in BarcodeConfigEffect) is dispatched before your `AppActions.SyncingSuccess` (in AppEffect). This is to ensure that you have received the `getBarcodeConfig`?

The problem with your solution is that you are forkJoining one single action, `BarcodeConfigActions.Sync`, and then mapping that action to an `AppActions.SyncingSuccess` before it is returned. This means that the `BarcodeConfigActions.Sync` never is emitted on the `actions$` observable, which is the observable you are tapping into in your `BarcodeConfigEffect`.

If your `syncMasterData$` effects´ only logic is to ensure that `BarcodeConfigActions.SyncSuccess` is called BEFORE `AppActions.SyncingSuccess`, perhaps just dispatch both actions forkJoined in your `BarcodeConfigEffect`?

```
@Effect() sync$ = this.actions$
.ofType<BarcodeConfigActions.Sync>(BarcodeConfigActions.SYNC)
.mergeMap(() => this.apiProvider.getBarcodeConfig())
.map((barcodeConfigs: BarcodeConfig[]) =>
{
    let barcodeConfigState = <barcodeConfig.State>{};
    barcodeConfigState.tenant = "COOKIE";
    barcodeConfigState.barcodeConfig = barcodeConfigs;
    /* NEW RETURN */
    return Observable.forkJoin(
                new AppActions.SyncingSuccess(),
                new BarcodeConfigActions.SyncSuccess({ barcodeConfigs: barcodeConfigState }));
})
.catch((error) =>
{
    this._store.dispatch(new AppActions.UnexpectedError(error));
    return Observable.of(new BarcodeConfigActions.SyncFailed)
})
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I have already solved it with a workaround. I pass a variable for sync into my state for every sync I do. (SyncBarcode, SyncTasks, Sync...). When sync is successful or not I will remove this variable and as soon as all is empty I know that my sync is done).